# Is the cache indexed by physical or virtual addresses?

Tags: caching

In modern microprocessor devices is the cache indexed by physical or virtual addresses? Suppose you are designing hardware architecture for a new microprocessor … what would be pros and cons of each approach?

Answer (score 0):

Both is possible. What is best is not so easily determined. You can fin a good explanation of the differences between physical und virtual caches [here](https://superuser.com/questions/745008/whats-the-difference-between-physical-and-virtual-cache).